# Java ArrayList.add causes freezes

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, arraylist, swingworker

I'm using a SwingWorker in my Java application to prevent the GUI from freezing.

The application uses 10% CPU and responds normally, but as soon as I add ArrayList.add() in a loop the GUI freezes and the application uses 100% CPU.

```
class TestWorker extends SwingWorker<Integer, Integer> {
    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground() throws Exception {
        ArrayList arr_1 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList arr_2 = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i = 0; i < 999999999; i++) {
            arr_1.add(2);
            arr_2.add(4);
        }

        return null;
    }
}

new TestWorker().execute();
```

Why does this happen? If I just do many calculations or create objects in a loop the GUI doesn't freeze, this only seems to happen using ArrayList.add().

Comment: Once the `ArrayList` reaches its max capacity, a new array has to be created and all the elements copied over.

Comment: You may be overloading your processor. Put a short `Thread.sleep(...)` into your loop and see what happens.

Comment: You're adding 1 billion elements to each list. It has to copy the internal array 25 times during the whole operation (it doubles in size every time it needs to grow, and starts from 16). What did you expect would happen?

Comment: Okay, I understand, but isn't there any way to store this amount of data without freezing? I'm making calculations and store the results in an ArrayList to retrieve them later.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels If that's the issue, `yield` is generally a better option than `sleep`.

Comment: For starters, if you know how large the list is going to be, preallocate it with enough capacity. Additionally, if you're using `ArrayList<Integer>`, replace that with `int[]`.

Comment: @chrylis If I use `int[] arr_1 = new int[999999999]` I have the same problem. Of course 999999999 is a bit much, but this happens very quickly.

Comment: Yeah, that's another thing. Java has to box the `int` value into an `Integer`. And has to do it a lot.

Comment: Run `top` or the equivalent on your program and see whether you're hitting a significant IO wait.